# How to save data in MKPinAnnotationViews

Tags: objective-c, ios, mkannotationview

I have a mapView that drops pins with a UILongPressGesture. The annotations have a callout button that brings up a new view when pressed. Within this view, there are text fields and a UIImage. What I want to do is save the text and image that the user inputs, but I need to be able to save the data for each individual pin. Does anyone know a good way of doing this?

Comment: Don't save it in the annotation view objects. The view objects are temporary, they can be recycled when a pin goes off-screen. Instead create a subclass of MKAnnotation which would contain the relevant information.

Comment: Ok. I am just confused about where to save the text and picture for each individual annotation. The user will have multiple annotations on the mapView.